# What GT bike is this?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I am thinking of buying this e-bike off of Craigslist but I am having difficulty figuring out if it an actual e-bike or a regular bike that has been converted.

I wiki'd the list of GT hardtails and Google Images didn't show me anything that popped out.

What we know:

- Hardtail Mountainbike
- The make is GT
- The Tires are Bontrager, possibly XR1

The guy isnt exactly answering my questions in complete English sentences.

[image: Bike]

Comment: That's not a hard tail.  Its a fully rigid bike.

Comment: Looks like a old, cheap kids bike to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a GT BMX Cruiser - the 24 inch - it looks like a 1999 model.

Cruisers are for BMX riders who are too old to be riding BMX :~)

Answer (score 5):

Doesn't look anything special - theres a one-piece crank, indicates a cheap low-grade bike.

The brakes are cantilevers which would be 90s at best.

The tyres will have been replaced at some time, so brand means nothing to the bike's model

The whole front wheel looks like its been swapped out for one of those hilltopper electric kits, which are not bad for a simple-fit kit.  Batteries tend to be expensive.

The whole bike looks like an overgrown BMX with a derailleur and rider bars with a reinforcement strut.

Answer (score 1):

Very definitely a conversion: motor in front wheel, strap-on battery pack.

Looks more like a BMX than a MTB. Frame looks small.